# Blocks from @ jafe

Tags: nonogram

This is my first nonogram puzzle, inspired by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe).

[image]

Comment: If there is no number next to a row or column, does that mean there are no shaded cells or that we don't know? The only reason I ask is that jafe used slightly different rules for some of the recent nonograms.

Comment: Yeah the complete row or column is empty.

Comment: So why are there blank rows at the top and bottom, instead of making the height 25?

Comment: @WeatherVane Could be that the finished image makes more sense with white at the top/bottom? (I'm guessing, haven't solved this yet...)

Comment: I've removed  a line from the top. I have left empty lines at top and bottom for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to guess in a couple of places but this is what I have

> [image]

Comment: Excellent!!!!..

Comment: downvoted the original post for *that font*. ;)